# react- onClick on item take the last index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with: `<br>`
when I click on any item, always I get the last index of the list in the "sliderItemClick" function. 
this is my code -

```
const _renderSliderItems = useCallback(
    (gallery, fullScreen) =>
      gallery.map((imageBlock, idx) => (
        <div key={`image-block-${fullScreen ? "fullScreen" : ""}-${idx}`}>
          <div
            className={cx("slider-item", {
              "full-screen": fullScreen,
            })}
            onClick={() => sliderItemClick(idx)}
          >
            {_renderImages(idx, imageBlock)}
          </div>
        </div>
      )),
    [gallery, fullScreen]
  );



 function sliderItemClick(idx) {
    if (!fullScreen) {
      setState({ ...state, initialSlide: idx, isModalOpen: true });
    }
  }
```

what is the solution?
thank.

Comment: Can you please share `sliderItemClick`'s code as well?

Comment: What is the reason behind using `useCallback` for this?

Comment: i added the sliderItemClick's code.